# mXParser derivative gives NAN

Tags: java, nan

I'm new to using the mXparser library. I need it to do some calculus problems. Therefore to start with i used 
`Expression e = new Expression("cos(1) - der(sin(x), x, 1)");
System.out.println(String.valueof(e.calculate());`

this give a NaN.

why is this happening. Both 1.7 and 1.8 jdk are giving these error.

But when i use,
`Argument a= new Argument("x=1");
Expression e=new Expression("cos(1)-der(sin(x),x)",a);
System.out.println(String.valueof(e.calculate()));`

gives the correct answer.  In the Docs it says that the arguments can be supplied as `der(sin(x),x,1)` as well. so Why its giving NaN?

Please help.

Comment: Looking at [the tool's release notes](http://mathparser.org/previous-releases/), it looks like the syntax you're trying to use has only been implemented as of v.4.1.0. Can you make sure you're not using an older version?

Comment: That was the issue. I was using v 4.0.0.now it's working

Comment: Nice, glad I got it right, I don't know the first thing about the tool. I'll transform my comment into an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `der( f(x), x, x0 )` you're trying to use has only been implemented since 4.1.0, and trying to use it in a prior version would lead to the result you're getting.

If you can't update, it looks like you will have to stick to using an `Argument`.